# Using jquery slider angularjs scope value is not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am doing a project using angularjs and in this project I am using a jquery slider. Using this slider I have to change a selectbox value its defined in one $scope array but its not working.

Here is an example code in this I just want to know how to change the scope value based on jquery slider

Html code

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='CompositionController'>


              <div class="thinkness-bar">
                                                <div class="popupslider">
                                                    <div id="testslider" class="jquery-slider"></div>                                                     
                                                    <input type="text" id="testamount" class="progressnumber" value="500"  >
                                                    <input type="hidden" id="testhdndfaltThick" name="testhdndfaltThick" value="50" /> 
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
           </div>
           {{value}}

</body>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/includes/jquery.1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/includes/jquery.1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/includes/jquery.ui.1.11.1.js"></script> 
</html>
```

script code

```
<script>
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('CompositionController', function ($scope,$http) 
{
    $scope.value =0 
     var sliderValue = [2,3,5,7,8,10,11,13,15,18,19];
    $("#testslider").slider({ 
                range: "min", 
                value: 8, 
                min: 1, 
                max: 20, 
                slide: function(event, ui) 
                { 
                  if(sliderValue.indexOf(ui.value)===-1 ) return false;
                         $("#testamount" ).val( ui.value);

                  } 
                }); 
               $( "#testamount" ).val( $( "#testslider" ).slider( "value" ) );  
               $scope.value =$( "#testamount" ).val(); 
});


</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add `$scope.$apply()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting the value in a jquery event, angular doesn't know that something has been updated and you need to call

```
$scope.$apply();
```

after setting $scope.value.

PS: I really hope this is just a test and not actual production code.

**Edit:**

Well there were a few problems: ng-app was missing from the body tag, I assume you meant to change the value with the slider ...

I made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ieLnWMv6zc52hdITsfII?p=preview):

Comment: ng-app is there in html tag

Comment: cool, my bad on the ng-app thing, I didn't see it. You did not have ng-view however.